# Getting Facebook age_range using app access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile) states that `public_profile` is enabled by default and, among the details allowed to retrieve from there, there is `age_range`.

I'm trying to retrieve such field using the Facebook app token. I can retrieve `name`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `picture`, etc... with the app access token. But when I specify the `age_range` in the `fields` query param of the request, `age_range` is not returned:

```
curl -i 'https://graph.facebook.com/<user_facebook_id>?access_token=<app-access-token>&fields=picture,age_range'
```

then I get

```
{"picture":{"data":{"height":50,"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/lookaside.facebook.com\/platform\/profilepic\/?asid=<user-facebook-id>&height=50&width=50","width":50}},"id":"<user-facebook-id>"}
```

Is `age_range` exposed only when the graph is accessed via the `/me` path and user Facebook access token?

Comment: Looks that way ... Not everything is available with an app token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked Facebook support and they confirmed that field is not accessible via the app token.